# Write several times a precise html code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am trying to make my code repeat several times these html elements on my page but I am stuck, my code works for the moment but I can't add html tags which have the same parents and I don't know why...

What I wanna do is a "vitrine" website for a friend's Etsy shop... I want the page to display all his articles... So I need to create a loop which writes as many html elements as articles...

Do you guys can help me ?

I am new to JavaScript by the way ;)

```js
let productCount = 8;

for (let i = 0; i <= productCount; i++) { // on repète la boucle autant de fois qu'il y a d'articles

      const newContainer = document.createElement('article');
      let container = document.getElementById("product-list");
      newContainer.classList.add("product");

      const newContent = document.createElement('div');
      let content = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
      newContent.classList.add("product-content");

      const newProductInfo = document.createElement('div');
      let productInfo = document.querySelector("#product-list > article > product-content");
      newProductInfo.classList.add("product-info");

      const newProductTitleColumn = document.createElement('div');
      let productTitleColumn = document.querySelector("#product-list > article > product-content >  product-info");
      newProductTitleColumn.classList.add("product-title-column");

      const newProductRow = document.createElement('div');
      let productRow = document.querySelector("#product-list > article > product-content > product-info > product-title-column");
      newProductRow.classList.add("product-row");

      const newProductTitle = document.createElement('h2');
      let productTitle = document.querySelector("#product-list > article > product-content > product-info > product-title-column > product-row");
      newProductTitle.classList.add("product-title");


      container.appendChild(newContainer).appendChild(newContent).appendChild(newProductInfo).appendChild(newProductTitleColumn).appendChild(newProductRow).appendChild(newProductTitle);

   

};
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #363636;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #bdbdbd;
}

.product-img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.product-title-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.product-info {
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 350px;
}

.product-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #363636;
}

.product-title {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.product-price {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.product-description {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.shipping-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 10px;
}

.product-quantity {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.product-link {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #eb6d20;
}
```

```html
<article class="product">
    <div class="product-content">
      <img src="Images/Products/IMG_4303.JPG" class="product-img">
      <div class="product-info">
        <div class="product-title-column">
        <div class="product-row">
          <h2 class="product-title">Bavoir élastique</h2>
          <h2 class="product-title">-</h2>
          <h2 class="product-price">5€</h2>
        </div>
        <p class="product-line"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="product-column">
        <p class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Recusandae minus tenetur
        ea placeat odit et doloremque laudantium incidunt blanditiis minima quaerat adipisci, nesciunt
        distinctio
        possimus quas odio nostrum rem commodi.</p>
        <div class="shipping-info">
          <p class="product-quantity">Livraison gratuite</p>
          <p class="product-quantity">9 en stock <i class="fas fa-check"></i></p>
        </div>
        <a class="product-link" href="#">Acheter sur Etsy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </article>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("product-list");` I don't see any element with that id.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, this code is between these tags :  <div class="product-list" id="product-list"></div>

Comment: Have you heard of the `<template>` element? Using it would allow you to type the html of each item and then clone the whole block, filling in details of products as required. In fact, the MDN page for it uses product items as its example. :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think that's exactly what I am needing !